# Ruby Controllers calling the Model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I am new to Ruby and I have a question.  I am trying to have a controller call a model class which would query a MySQL database.

What is the correct way to set this up?  I am trying not to use scaffolding so that I learn how to do this by hand.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what you want?

Comment: rails has great documentation and lots of very easy to understand tutorials. take a look at "getting started with rails" (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

when calling index, you will find post in database which id is equal to id given in paramaterer (http://localhost/my_controllers/id)